# Connect mysql database using odbc in vbnet

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, odbc

I have a mysql database on phpmyadmin, I installed the connector 6.8.3 (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) I add a reference on the driver ((c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll) and I use this connexion string : Private _connexionParams As String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 6.8.3 UNICODE Driver};Server=localhost;Database=GestionDuPersonnel;User=test;Password=test;" (from : http://www.connectionstrings.com/mys...ctor-odbc-5-2/).

When I start my program I get this error and I don't understand why : "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Thanks

Comment: you should refer this:http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just do this thing

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Test
    Public Sub Connexion()
    Dim connStr As String = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=GestionDuPersonnel;UID=test;PASSWORD=test"
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    connection.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And use the connector .NET 6.8.3 : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 1):

sample try this:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 Dim MyConString As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 6.8.3 UNICODE Driver};" +
 "SERVER=localhost;" +
 "DATABASE=test;" +
 "UID=root;" +
 "OPTION=3"
 Dim MyConnection As New OdbcConnection(MyConString)

 MyConnection.Open()
 MsgBox(MyConnection.State.ToString)
 End Sub
End Class
```

refer this link: http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/connecting-mysql-and-vb-net-using-odbc-driver/

Comment: I just try your code but I get this error message : "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" which is the same think as before.. But you write : "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" but I installed the connector 6.8.3 so are you sure that's the good way ?

Thanks for reply

Comment: I'm just asking sample only, you should change your details

Comment: you should change the driver name like: `MySQL ODBC 6.8.3 UNICODE Driver`

Comment: this code with connexion string as : 
`Dim MyConString As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 6.8.3 UNICODE Driver};" +
        "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=test;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=root;"` 
don't work, always the same error

Comment: No, I'll doing some change, now you should copy and paste and then run the code

Comment: Always the same thing.. I get all your code like this : 

`Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MyConString As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 6.8.3 UNICODE Driver};" +
        "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=test;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "OPTION=3"
        Dim MyConnection As New OdbcConnection(MyConString)

        MyConnection.Open()
        MsgBox(MyConnection.State.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class`

And I get the same error message..

Comment: The same as usual, "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" on MyConnection.Open()

Comment: Finnally I do another things which works, I will post the solution and mark as solved, thanks for your help ! It was nice